# Android HttpPosting Json object

Tags: java, android

I am looking for some help posting a json object.  I am fairly new to working with APIs and programming on android and have followed a few of the suggested answers on stack but with no success.  Could anyone offer some help or point me in the right direction? I would greatly appreciate it.

```
public void submitInfo(View view) {

    try {
        JSONObject jSonUserInfo = new JSONObject();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

            jSonUserInfo.put("username", userName);
            jSonUserInfo.put("email", userEmail);
            jSonUserInfo.put("hash", userPassword);

        StringEntity entity = new StringEntity(jSonUserInfo.toString());

            entity.setContentType("application/json");
            entity.setContentEncoding(new BasicHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json"));
            httpPost.setEntity(entity);

        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

        HttpResponse response;

        response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        Log.d("Response from api", response.toString());

        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Results.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

Logcat:

> 11-19 13:37:16.256: E/AndroidRuntime(19671): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   11-19 13:37:16.256: E/AndroidRuntime(19671):
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the
>   activity 11-19 13:37:16.256: E/AndroidRuntime(19671):     at
>   android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3633) 11-19 13:37:16.256:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(19671):  at
>   android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4240) 11-19 13:37:16.256:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(19671):  at
>   android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17721) 11-19
>   13:37:16.256: E/AndroidRuntime(19671):    at
>   android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730) 11-19
>   13:37:16.256: E/AndroidRuntime(19671):    at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92) 11-19
>   13:37:16.256: E/AndroidRuntime(19671):    at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 11-19 13:37:16.256:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(19671):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103) 11-19
>   13:37:16.256: E/AndroidRuntime(19671):    at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 11-19
>   13:37:16.256: E/AndroidRuntime(19671):    at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525) 11-19 13:37:16.256:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(19671):  at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
>   11-19 13:37:16.256: E/AndroidRuntime(19671):  at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553) 11-19
>   13:37:16.256: E/AndroidRuntime(19671):    at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 11-19 13:37:16.256:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(19671): Caused by:
>   java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

Comment: What is your problem?

Comment: you probably just need `EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity())`

Comment: sorry, as of right now the app crashes with "could not execute method of the activity"

Comment: Get the logs and edit them into your question.

Comment: It looks like you could be executing some code that should be in a background thread in the main(UI) thread. Check out AsyncTasks